# How to define Upload scalar without GraphQL Schema Language?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

There is a sample code where Upload scalar defined with GraphQL Schema Language:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools'
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'apollo-upload-server'

const typeDefs = `
  scalar Upload
`

const resolvers = {
  Upload: GraphQLUpload
}

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })
```

How can we do the same thing without GraphQL Schema language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [GraphQLSchemaType](http://graphql.github.io/graphql-js/type/#graphqlscalartype) object.

```
const uploadType = new GraphQLScalarType({ name: "Upload" });
```

You'd then have to use that as the type of `GraphQLField` and `GraphQLInputObjectField` objects.

(In my experience the GraphQL schema language is more compact and readable than building up a language-native object model and in practice I'd stick with the form you have in the question.)